# Fuzzy Image Enhancement

Tags: image, fuzzy-logic, image-enhancement

I need to implement an algorithm that makes Fuzzy Image Enhancement but I can't find any implementations to start with. Could you point me to some (googled with no success).

Comment: A google search brings up this immediately: http://pami.uwaterloo.ca/tizhoosh/enhance.htm. If you're after something implemented in a specific language then you'll need to specify the language.

Comment: also -- is this homework? if so, i'll retag ..

Answer (score 1):

The [contrast intensification example](http://www.scribd.com/doc/47361487/2002-Putting-Fuzzy-Logic-to-Work-An-Intro-to-Fuzzy-Rule) is a classic one as it is one of the most straightforward applications of fuzzy logic to image processing.

Here is a code snippet using Mathematica: http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/fuzzylogic/examples/processing.html